# View CPU usage by process in Android ADB Shell

Tags: process, adb

Using a standard linux shell, I can use `ps` to get process information, including ram and cpu.

On the `adb shell` equivalent, I do not see CPU usage:

```
root@generic_x86:/ # ps
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE   RSS    WCHAN    PC        NAME
u0_a99   3129  947   1630132 156124 ffffffff b753f355 S com.example.app
```

How can I view CPU usage by app in the shell?

Comment: Would `top -n 1` do for you?

Comment: Yes, yes it does.